# HTML Bootstrap 3 not adding active class to UL LI

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to use scroll-spy to add an active class to the `ul li` on a one page scroll and sticky nav, for some unknown reason i cant get this work with-in my project.
Below is the layout of my menu:

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top my-nav" role="navigation">
    <div class="container_full height">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll height">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="logo-holder">
            <img class="" src="img/logo-p.png"/>
            <span>
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#home-page">xxxxxx</a>
                <i>xxxxxxx</i>
            </span>
            </div> 
        </div>  
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse height">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav height">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#home-page">item1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#item2">item2</a>
                </li>                   
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#item3">item3</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#item4">item4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container_full" id="site">
<section class="parallax">
<!-- HOME PAGE DISPLAY -->  
    <div id="home-page" class="home-g height-650">
        <div class="parallax-layer parallax-back height-650" >
            <div class="home">
            </div>
            //many divs css parallax--
```

The nav js file is below:

```
 $('.parallax').scroll(function() {

if ($('.parallax').scrollTop() > 100) { 
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    $(".my-nav").addClass("nav-resize");



} else {

    $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    $(".my-nav").removeClass("nav-resize");
    $(".moveLogo").removeClass("moveLogo-resize");
}
});


$(function() {
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    var position =  $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top + $('.parallax').scrollTop() ;

    $('html,body,.parallax').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: position
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

    event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

If i was to use the above method without the parallax divs etc this will work with no problems but at the moment the **li** class is active always on the **last li item** when scrolling down the page.

[image]

green = scroll-able content inside parent container" Blue ", green divs are to target id's.

```
 .blue{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;

 }

 .green // Has many divs
```

I tried the obvious to target the green > divs but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How about create a jsfiddle? That might help people help you

Comment: I don't understand, you don't seem to be using Boostrap's `scrollspy` function?

Comment: From what i have read in docs, i am limited to only relative positioning. As the parallax is using absolute positioning I will need to create  script to detect the div and place the ul li class as necessary. js fiddle will be lengthy at this time to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code didn't give enough to go off of, so I added a series of divs that are 1000px tall and have different background colors - all of which corresponded to the IDs in your nav menu - scroll spy is working. Perhaps you just didn't have enough content to scroll or were implementing the IDs incorrectly?

Note that I'm also using recent versions of Bootstrap and jQuery...

[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/ayworbf4/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>


<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top my-nav" role="navigation">
    <div class="container_full height">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll height">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="logo-holder">

            <span>
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#home-page">xxxxxx</a>
                <i>xxxxxxx</i>
            </span>
            </div> 
        </div>  
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse height">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav height">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#home-page">item1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#item2">item2</a>
                </li>                   
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#item3">item3</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#item4">item4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container_full" id="site">
<section class="parallax">
<!-- HOME PAGE DISPLAY -->  
    <div id="home-page" class="home-g height-650">
        <div class="parallax-layer parallax-back height-650" >
            <div class="home">
            </div>
            <div style="height:1000px; background:pink"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="item2" class="home-g height-650">
        <div class="parallax-layer parallax-back height-650" >
            <div class="home">
            </div>
            <div style="height:1000px; background:red"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="item3" class="home-g height-650">
        <div class="parallax-layer parallax-back height-650" >
            <div class="home">
            </div>
            <div style="height:1000px; background:green"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It was an issue i overseen, so you can have the bounty because of your efforts, Thanks for the interest.